# what is the best way to get the maximum tps server can support

Tags: rest, tomcat, jmeter, performance-testing

I have 20 Rest API's build using Jersey and Apache Client.I want to know the max TPS my server can withstand, using JMeter tool.what is the best way to achieve such kind of performance scenario goal.

Comment: If you are trying to measure server performance then [Apache Benchmark(AB)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) or [HTTPerf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf) would be the best solution.

Comment: @Adnan `ab` is actually not a very good tool. It's got some serious threading issues and should mostly be considered a toy. If you want to apply real load, use a real load-testing tool like `JMeter (if you want to stick with Apache products).

Comment: Thanks alot @ChristopherSchultz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all build a Test Plan. I believe it should have at least 20 [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to cover all your endpoints and a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send correct `Content-Type` header. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for details.
2. Once you have the Test Plan - run it with 1-2 virtual users to check that it does what it supposed to be doing. Inspect requests and responses details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Modify requests if needed.
3. Configure your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) so load is increased **gradually**, i.e. provide reasonable Ramp-Up time
4. Once you're happy with your test behaviour disable the View Results Tree listener and [run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
5. Analyze the results using i.e. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). The value which interests you lives in **Hits Per Second** graph

Comment: Thanks alot Dmitri.Should I need to increase the load in incremental manner to record max TPS?Is there any need to include thinktime in this kind of scenarios

Comment: I believe you should always increase the load incrementally, otherwise you won't get the full picture demonstrating correlation of virtual users arrival with the application under test behavior. In regards to thinktime, normally it is not required for direct API tests, however if you are simulating i.e. mobile application - it should be considered. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for details